# How to put block elements in another row with width 100%, if they don't fit in one row using css?

Tags: css

I have the following requirements: when several block elements don’t fit in one row put them into another and make them to be 100% width, if they fit in one row than take auto width. So, the question is the next one: is it possible to implements this using only css? Thanks  a lot!

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container2 .box {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
if they fit in one row than take auto width
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>  
</div>

<br/>
If they don’t fit in one row put<br/>
them into another and make them to be 100% width
<div class="container container2">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Sorry, for making the question unclear. Updated the post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Use `flex-wrap` to automatically create a new row when first row overflows.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

---

### For Dynamic Content

```js
$(".container").each(function() {
  if ($(this).height() > 100) {
    $(".box", this).each(function() {
      $(this).addClass("stretch");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.stretch {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">text</div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">text</div>
  <div class="box">more text than text</div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">text</div>
  <div class="box">more text than text</div>
  <div class="box">Lots more text than more text than text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this too. But the main difficulty is that the width of this boxes (labels) is calculated in run-time according to the text-content inside.So, if there is a little text and a few labels fit in a row, then their width will be auto.But if the text-content is bigger and they do not fit in a row, then the width of the labels will be 100% and each one will be located in it's own row.

Comment: In which case you would need to use code behind or javascript to detect the wrap has occured and then make css changes.

Comment: @User147 see changes above for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I've use your answer as the base, customize a little for my own needs and now everything is working as expected. Thanks!